# Count all elements from some day

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have this code:

```
$currentDate =  Carbon::now()->subDays(1);
$count = MyPosts::where('created_at', $currentDate)->count();
```

Problem is that it doesn't find any elements because time can be different. I  want to count all elements from particular day.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare it to the specific day, and ask Carbon to give you the date rather than the datetime. The syntax is pretty simple:

```
$date = now()->subDay()->toDateString();
$count = MyPosts::whereDate('created_at', $date)->count();
```

On a related note, it's better to name models in the singular (MyPost) because each instance of it is a single object. The table is plural my_posts because it contains many of them.

Comment: You missed the column in `whereDate('column', $date)`. Your code can also be simplified to: `$count = MyPosts::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::yesterday())->count();` (note the `Carbon::yesterday()` method, which is the same as `Carbon::today()->subDay()` or `Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->subDay()`)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that was clumsy.